# Is there a way to generate a list of unique values, extracted from more than one array in excel or google sheets?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, unique

Can I generate a list of unique values from different columns in different sheets?
It can be in excel or google sheets.

Something like:

=sort(unique(column1,column2,column3,false,false))

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes for gs:

```
=SORT(UNIQUE({Sheet1!A1:A100; B10:B30; Sheet5!C8:C}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Say we have:

[image]

and we want a sorted list of the items in both columns.

First place the following `UDF()` in a standard module:

```
Public Function stack(ParamArray arr()) As Variant
    Dim r As Range, arr_cnt As Long, i As Long, cell_cnt As Long
    Dim Liist, Li As Long, rr As Range, ic As Long, ir As Long
    Dim iir As Long, iic As Long
    
    arr_cnt = UBound(arr)
    cell_cnt = 0
    For i = 0 To arr_cnt
        Set r = arr(i)
        cell_cnt = cell_cnt + r.Count
    Next i
    
    ReDim Liist(1 To cell_cnt, 1 To 1)
    Li = 1
    
    For i = 0 To arr_cnt
        Set r = arr(i)
        ic = r.Columns.Count
        ir = r.Rows.Count
        If ic > 1 And ir > 1 Then
            For iic = 1 To ic
                For iir = 1 To ir
                    Liist(Li, 1) = r(iir, iic)
                    Li = Li + 1
                Next iir
            Next iic
            
        Else
            For Each rr In r
                Liist(Li, 1) = rr.Value
                Li = Li + 1
            Next rr
        End If
    Next i
    
    stack = Liist
End Function
```

The UDF takes a group of ranges and produces a single column-compatible array of values.  Pick a cell and enter:

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(stack(A1:A6,C1:C5)))
```

[image]

Comment: This has worked perfectly for me in most cases, however, there's one particular situation where I'm getting a #Value error. I was wondering if you could help me solve the issue?

Essentially, I have three tables where I'd like to stack the values in column A from each table. Except, I'd only like it stack the values in Column A where the value of Column B = X. I'd then like to wrap the stacked range in a UNIQUE function.

My issue is that I'm using a Filter function on each column to retrieve the desired values. Unfortunately when I nest that within the UDF, I get an error :(

Thanks!